# how to pass data from xml parser into list view

Tags: android, xml, parsing, listview

I have this parsing example and it works fine, but I can't figure out, how to get all the data in a listview. Can you help me to find a solution? thanks

```
public class XMLParsingExample extends ListActivity {

    /** Create Object For SiteList Class */
    SitesList sitesList = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
            // LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(1);

            /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
            TextView name[];

            try {

                    /** Handling XML */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                    /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
                    URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://xxx/xxx/example.xml");

                    /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                    MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }

            /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
            sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

            /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
            for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
                    name[i] = new TextView(this);
                    name[i].setText("Name = " + sitesList.getName().get(i));
                    layout.addView(name[i]);
            }

            /** Set the layout view to display */
            setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you XML is just a collection of simple string you can parse it somehow to `String[]` and then just use [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

If your data is more complicated, you can implement your own [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) child and do all the bindings here. It will accept parsed XML in the constructor and then use it to get all data and bind it to views.

Comment: it is a simple collection of strings and i have tried to use an arrayadapter, but somehow it's not working. isn't there an example code i could use?

Comment: @bebe Look at this example on using `ArrayAdapter` with `ListView` : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html